# Detecting if the image has the required object in it

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I have set of images(more than 2000) of the type given below which may have the L shaped object as shown in the picture(i have circled it). I need to find all the images which will have them.
I have not yet studied computer vision and stuff so please tell me how to proceed.
[image: all are 5472 * 3078 in dimension]

Comment: You can use deep learning object detection techniques. If you need to quickly test if this will work, you can try out https://nanonets.com/drone

Comment: The question is too broad at the moment. Could you please provide additional examples and information on your problem?  you could use deep learning object detection or classic computer vision techniques, but some more information is needed to give meaningful advice.

Comment: I have many images like the one shown above which may have L shaped objects which I have circled in the above picture. I have to go through each of those pictures and have to find if it has that L shaped object. (orientation of that L shaped object will vary)